# Rails js.erb not rendering partial file but get response file rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I have the following partial files

```
_report.html.erb

<h5>REPORT</h5>
<hr/>
<%= link_to "Extract REPORT", "#", :class => 'btn btn-primary', id: 'load_panel' %>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="row">
  <% rand = Time.now.to_i - Random.new.rand(1..Time.now.to_i) %>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="hidden" id="randValue" value="<%= rand %>" data-validate="false" data-hidden="true"/>
    <div>
      <b>File Name</b>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div id="application-attachments-<%= rand %>" class="col-xs-12">
      <%= render partial: 'report_attachment', locals: {application_attachments: f.object.application_attachments} %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


_report_attachment.html.erb

<% application_attachments.each do |attachment| %>
    <div class="fields">
        <%= render "report_attachment_fields", rep_attachment: attachment, instalment: true, type: 'application_assignment' %>
    </div>
<% end %>


_report_attachment_fields.html.erb

<div class="row attachment_display">
  <% if rep_attachment.attachment? && rep_attachment.attachment.model.share_file %>
    <% if @action == "show" && @account_type %>
      <div class="col-md-6 ellipis">
        <%= link_to File.basename(rep_attachment.attachment.path), rep.attachment.url, target: "_blank", id: 'view_file', :data => { application_attachment_id: rep_attachment.id } %>
        <%= rep_attachment.active %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Upon initial load, it loads all 3 files accordingly. But Upon clicking Extract CTOS, it makes a javascript request

```
application.js

$('body').on('click', '#load_panel', function(event) {
    object_selected = $(this)
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/applications/generate_report?application_id='+$(this).attr('data-application-id')+'&rand_value='+$(this).attr('data-rand-value'),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        object_selected.removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    })
  })
```

On calling the GET request, it will call this method

```
def generate_report
  @rand_value = params[:rand_value]
  @rep_application_attachment = @application.rep_attachment
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Which should call this js.erb file

```
generate_report.js.erb

$("#application-attachments-#{@rand_value}").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'report_attachment', application_attachments: @rep_application_attachment) %>");
```

The problem now is that i dont get an error and it says generate_report.js.erb has been rendered but it doesnt render anything. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

solved it. It had to do with my ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/applications/generate_report?application_id='+$(this).attr('data-application-id')+'&rand_value='+$(this).attr('data-rand-value'),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        object_selected.removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    })
```

should be this instead. by not including `datatype ='script'` and correct format, even though my js.erb got called, it wasn't executed.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/applications/generate_report?application_id='+$(this).attr('data-application-id')+'&rand_value='+$(this).attr('data-rand-value'),
      data: {
        format: 'js'
      },
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(data) {
        object_selected.removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to specify 'partial' option to render template using `render` method.

#### Try this

**generate_report.js.erb**

```
$("#application-attachments-#{@rand_value}").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'report_attachment', application_attachments: @rep_application_attachment) %>");
```

your original code:

```
$("#application-attachments-#{@rand_value}").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'report_attachment', application_attachments: @rep_application_attachment) %>");
```

> #### Rendering partials
>
> *Partial rendering in a controller is most commonly used together with Ajax calls that only update one or a few elements on a page without reloading. Rendering of partials from the controller makes it possible to use the same partial template in both the full-page rendering (by calling it from within the template) and when sub-page updates happen (from the controller action responding to Ajax calls). By default, the current layout is not used.*
>
> **For more information about render**
>
> https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to interpolate your ruby instance variable the wrong way (you're using Ruby's string interpolation syntax `"#{}"`), when you need to use ERB `"<%= %>"`.

This should work:

```
$("#application-attachments-<%= @rand_value %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'report_attachment', application_attachments: @rep_application_attachment) %>");
```

Comment: still doesnt work. somehow it calls the js.erb but nothing gets populated. I have even just tried looking for another div and tried smthg like this `$('#new_div').html("testing")` but still it doesnt get populated. Somehow it just goes in but doesnt execute anything written in the js.erb file. Very weird. Does this have anythg to do wt the fact that the AJAX get function doesnt hv any `remote=true` involved?